# Remote Notifications with background update

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm implementing Remote Notifications and I'm trying to update the app before the notification is shown to the user.

The problem is that the notification is shown before I finish updating the data, what am I missing?

```
public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification (UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
{
   //Some code to update the data - the notification is shown before this executed.

     completionHandler (UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);

}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The method above will only be triggered if your app is actively running in the foreground. You can then react to the delivery. I think you should read into these guidelines to understand the complete flow: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1

Comment: As I understand it does:
"when your app is running in the foreground or background. In addition, if you enabled the remote notifications background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a push notification arrives"